# Trying to play multiple videos in sequence on one flash video player?

Tags: html, flash, html5-audio

I have a regular flash video player set up and I am able to play one video successfully. However, I have 3 different videos that I need to play in sequence on this one video player.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this using regular HTML (it's not very hard in HTML5)? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: When you say you have a flash video player, do you mean you are using Strobe or have you built one using OSMF or are you making NetConnection and NetStreams yourself.

Basically: do you have access to the actionscript of the player or do you just have a .swf?

Comment: I just have the .swf I believe.

Comment: That is interesting. You are at the mercy of the forward thinking of the dev(s) behind your swf. I a grimm thought. I believe it is flow player that supports playlists out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the .fla source file then you might want to look into another 3rd party solution, such as [Flow Player](http://flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/playlist.html) or [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16006/javascript-playlist-in-the-jw-embedder)

**EDIT:** [According to the JWPlayer docs](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options#behavior)

```
repeat ( none )
What to do when the mediafile has ended. Has several options:

none: do nothing (stop playback) whever a file is completed.
list: play each file in the playlist once, stop at the end.
always: continously play the file (or all files in the playlist).
single: continously repeat the current file in the playlist.
```

So when you initialize it in the javascript, add the repeat arg to your existing `.setup()` call:

```
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    ...
    'repeat': 'always',
    ...
    'id': 'playerID',
    ...
```